# open url in ruby controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to call some php script from ROR controller, so I tried to use open("url"), but it didn't work.
For example,

```
def successful_login
  open("http://stackoverflow.com")
  redirect_to home_url
end
```

Errno::EINVAL in UsersController#create
Invalid argument - http://stackoverflow.com

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like forgot require open-uri: `require 'open-uri';open('http://host/').read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get('www.example.com', '/index.html')
```

[The API docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M001361)

Comment: Oh, thx! Seems it become closer to solution, but I have another error (absolutely unrecognizable): Errno::ECONNRESET (????????? ???? ????????????? ???????? ???????????? ???????????.):

Comment: open up a console/terminal and load up irb. then type in 'require 'net/http' . And `Net::HTTP.get('www.google.com', '/intl/en/about/')` without the quotes. See if it gives you any output. If it does, it works fine. What URL are you trying to hit? can you open it up with a browser?

Comment: It works now, when I call the localhost url. It doesn't work with the outside urls, in spite of fact, that I can open it in browser. Seems it's the development environment issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alex glad it works for you. You could 'accept' my answer BTW ;)

Answer (score 0):

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.get('/index.html')
}
puts res.body
```